# azure cannot "create Run as account"

Tags: azure, azure-runbook, azure-rbac

Daniel explains it [here](https://www.danielstechblog.io/start-and-stop-azure-vms-without-access-to-microsoft-azure/) how to start and stop a VM located on Azure.

I cannot do this as I cannot find **Create Azure Run As Account**
I believe my account is limited by the account owner.
What do I Need to ask to get this permission?

I have a Contributor role with Access to one particular subscription.

I am in a middle Company owned by a bigger Company.

I would like to give a developer the ability to start and stop a VM he is using.

Comment: This is off topic. Sorry I forgot. What was written by Jayendran is a perfect answer.  Should my question be deleted or moved to Server Fault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said this is because you don't have enough privileges(roles) to `Create Azure run as Account`.You need to get `Owner`/`Co-Administator` role of that particular subscription to enable this.

[Difference between owner role and contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)

You need to request your company higher official who has owner roles for your Azure subscription to add your account as `Owner`/`Co-Administator` role for that particular subscription

Like it explained [here](https://helpdesk.kaseya.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115002521691-How-to-check-add-Owner-role-for-Azure-resources-)