# Azure unable to create a run as account

Tags: azure

Azure Run As account creation error
An error occurred while creating the Azure Run As account for account 'xxxxxxxxxx'.
Error details:
You don't have enough permissions to access service principal needed for the Run as account in the AAD tenant. See https://aka.ms/AARunAsPermissions for more details.

dc

Comment: Interesting link. Didn't click on it. However, here are some other links that you can look at, as it relates to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326806/azure-cannot-create-run-as-account   ------     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443245/can-not-create-a-run-as-account-and-i-do-have-owner-rights-in-the-subscription    -----  Perhaps post some screenshots (with sensitive info blurred/removed) so we can better help you. Welcome to SO btw!

Comment: Hi ,If my answer is helpful to you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to end the thread, you just need to click the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error message has clearly stated your problem, and you need to grant the account the subscription [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#azure-roles) `owner` role.

Use the subscription administrator account to log in to the Azure portal>**Subscriptions**>**your Subscriptions**

[image]

In addition, you also need to ensure that you have the permission to create AAD applications. Use the **tenant administrator** to log in to Azure portal> **Azure AD**>**User settings** and set `Users can register applications` to `Yes`.

[image]